# RxAndroid and button events?

Tags: android, rx-android

Anyone know how to get an click from a Button click using RxAndroid ?

NO, this is NOT a duplicate.  Too much has changed.

I tried:

- Events.click() ... has been removed
- RxTextView.editorActions() ... assumed to work because TextView is the superclass of Button ... does did not get any events out of it
- ViewObservable.clicks()  .... has been removed or moved to RxBindings (supposedly, but I could not find it in there!)

My Gradle dependencies are:

```
compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.14'
compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.0.1'
compile 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding:0.2.0'
```

Ideas anyone ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of 0.3.0, you need to use `RxView.clicks()`.  Here is an example that logs the click.

```
 RxView.clicks(button).subscribe(new Action1<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void call(Void aVoid) {
                // Replace below with your click handling code
                Log.d(TAG, "Clicked");
            }
        });
```

Comment: RxView.clickEvents were removed on 22.10.2015 - changelog: https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: Additional side note: If the view is relevant for some reason - like when adding an onClick listener to a recycleradapter, then all one need to do is defined the action via new Action1<View>() .... the method being called will then read public void call(View view){...}

Answer (score 1):

Also, If you want to improve the event to avoid multiple clicks, you can use:

```
@BindView(R.id.my_button)
Button myButton;

RxView.clicks(myButton)
      .throttleFirst(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS, AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
      .subscribe(s -> {
            // Do anything when I do click  
            Log.d(TAG, "Clicked");
      });
```